# Postgres. Yii 2. Поиск в массиве значений

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, запрос

Нужно добавить в билдер условие, выборка полей если значения свойства поля(json) есть в некоторм массиве.
Например поле _data имеет значение {"page_url": "kozha"}.
`->andWhere("_data->>'page_url' = 'kozha'")` - работает.
Но как проверять в массиве? Типа

```
->andWhere("_data->>'page_url' = ['kozha','metal']")
```

Ошибка

Answer (score 0):

```
->andWhere(['in', new Expression("(_data->>'page_url')"),['kozha','metal']])
```